# Flagging has twice option as "it is duplicate" & "duplicate of"

Tags: discussion, flags

For flagging as duplicate there is **twice** option as following:

- At main list > "**it is duplicate...**"

---

[image: screen0]

---

- **Under** "It should be closed for another reason" > "**duplicate of...**"

---

[image: screen1]

---

Now what is difference between them? or **Why option provided twice**?

Comment: In fact, it appears triple =) There is separate _close_ menu for 3k users.

Comment: @Danatela Ok. but it (close-menu) is for only 3k users but has above mentioned 2 options any difference?

Answer (score 3):

Nice catch, but I would consider it a feature as opposed to a bug.